# How to mount NFS share on Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, nfs, containers

I'm registered for the Azure Files NFSv4 preview, and I cannot seem to find a way to mount NFS file shares on ACI. I have tried the following:

1. Created a virtual network in eastus with two subnets, one specific to aci
2. Changed NFS storage account networking to only allow connections from above vnet:
   [image]
3. Deployed container with the following json:

   ```json
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "location": "eastus",
      "name": "nfs-test",
      "properties": {
        "osType": "Linux",
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "sshd",
            "properties": {
              "image": "boldidea.azurecr.io/ssh-test",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 22,
                  "protocol": "TCP"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 1,
                  "memoryInGB": 1.5
                }
              },
              "volumeMounts": [
                {
                  "mountPath": "/mnt/user-storage",
                  "name": "user-storage"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "azureFile": {
              "shareName": "ide-user-storage",
              "storageAccountKey": "(redacted)",
              "storageAccountName": "ideworkspacestoragenfs"
            },
            "name": "user-storage"
          }
        ],
        "imageRegistryCredentials": [
          {
            "server": "(redacted)",
            "username": "(redacted)",
            "password": "(redacted)"
          }
        ],
        "ipAddress": {
          "type": "Private",
          "ports": [
            {
              "port": 22,
              "protocol": "TCP"
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/(redacted)/resourceGroups/ideResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles/aci-network-profile-ide-vnet-eastus-aci"
        }
      }
    }
   ```

The deployment hangs for roughly 30 minutes before failing with the error "Failed to mount Azure File Volume". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through this issue w/ Azure support, and finally got to the ACI team who confirmed that NFS is not currently supported on container instances.

Comment: What is the preferred way to mount blob storage from a storage account to a ACI container?